# Chrome CSS3 Scrollable div won't render until animation finished

Tags: html, css, angular, animation, web

I am developing a simple flashcard using Angular, but I have an issue where the back of a div being transformed by rotateY(180deg) won't be rendered until the animation is complete:

[Example](https://giphy.com/gifs/Ge7zTc2pwVR2o/html5)

This doesn't happen if the div isn't scrollable.

The HTML used is as followed, and the innerHTML is just injected with text:

```
<div class="card-container">
<div class="flip-container" [class.flip]="isFlipped" [class.fadeOut]="isFadeOut">
  <div class="flipper" [class.noanimate]="isNotAnimating">
    <div class="front" [innerHTML]="cardsToStudy[currentCardIndex].front | safeHTML" (click)="toggleFlip()">
      <!-- front content -->
    </div>
    <div class="back" [innerHTML]="cardsToStudy[currentCardIndex].back | safeHTML" (click)="toggleFlip()">
      <!-- back content -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I've spent the last day trying to fix this, however haven't had any luck so far. This happens on Chrome Mobile and Desktop.

Any thoughts on what is happening and any possible fixes would be very welcome!